# Restrict types in Java for use in a List

Tags: java, generics

How can I pass a `List<T>` with a set of certain allowed types I did not declare to a method.

E.g. Restrict types to Integer, Boolean and `String`:

```
// Pseudo code
public void method(List<Integer OR Boolean OR String> myList);
```

---

If I use `List<Object>` I can put everything into that list:

```
public void method(List<Object> myList);
```

If I use List I can put all instances of `Parent` and its subclasses into that list:

```
public void method(List<Parent> myList);
```

That would be enough if I am the one who declares those subclasses (`AllowedTypeA extends Parent`). But what can I do when I'm not the owner of the classes I want to use (I cannot make `Integer` extend `Parent`)?

Comment: You can't express "or" type constraints in Java.  Can you explain what method you're trying to implement that would need that sort of constraint?

Comment: Generics is probably the wrong solution.  They are supposed to be "generic", hence the name.  If you can only support certain types (or have logic specific to the type), then you should probably have overloaded methods for each specific type.

Comment: @mellamokb Though in this case overloading would not work, all of the `List<...>` arguments would erase to `List`, so there would be a conflict unless there are other parameters (or name then differently, which case it is not overloading).

Comment: @LouisWasserman The List will be serialized as a flat JSON object without arrays or object as properties. Only `Integer`s, `Boolean`s and `String`s.

Comment: It sounds like you ought to create ` FlatObject` class with subclasses for integer, boolean, and string data, and have a list of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, I would prefer @laune's solution much more. I'd prefer type safety and compile errors over willy-nilly throwing a bunch of things into a list and forgetting to add the permitted Type.

That being said, it is still possible to do, though you'll have to do a bunch of extra stuff to make this practical, i.e. if you remove the object type, you should also probably remove all objects that are associated with it, and the other methods need to be overridden such as `addAll` to ensure proper functionality.

This approach makes it more flexible compared to laune's though, because you can add permittedTypes at any time. For your situation, probably not the best, but the general question is still intriguing enough that I took a shot. Maybe you want some of your Lists to store Integers, but not others. You can do so using the `addPermittedObject` method.

```
public class SelectiveList extends ArrayList<Object> {
    //the (types of) objects that we can store
    private ArrayList<Object> permittedObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // put an Object type into the list
    public boolean addPermittedObject(Object o) {
        for (Object type : permittedObjects) {
            if (type.getClass() == o.getClass()) {
                return false; // if we already have it, do not add it again
            }
        }
        return permittedObjects.add(o); // else let's add it
    }

    // remove the Object type
    public boolean removePermittedObject(Object o) {
        for (Object type : permittedObjects) {
            if (type.getClass() == o.getClass()) {
                return permittedObjects.remove(type);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object o) {
        for (Object type : permittedObjects) {
            if (type.getClass() == o.getClass()) {
                return super.add(o); // go ahead and add the item since it
                                        // matches our list
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SelectiveList selectiveList = new SelectiveList();
    selectiveList.add("Potato");
    selectiveList.add(1);
    selectiveList.add(true);
    System.out.println(selectiveList.size()); // prints 0
    // these objects need to be initialized, but their contents do not
    // matter
    selectiveList.addPermittedObject(new String());
    selectiveList.addPermittedObject(new Boolean(false));
    selectiveList.addPermittedObject(new Integer(1));
    selectiveList.add("Potato");
    selectiveList.add(1);
    selectiveList.add(true);
    System.out.println(selectiveList.size()); // prints 3
}
```

Comment: There is, as so often, the decision to be made whether a (perhaps more rigid but) type-safe approach or a very flexible (even runtime configurable!) approach is preferable.

Comment: It would be preferable to keep the classes in a `List<Class<?>> permittedTypes` instead of objects which keeps some objects unnecessarily lying around and requires the creation of representatives just to configure the type.

Answer (score 7):

The best thing to do is to wrap this mixed list into a class and provide methods to add just what you want to permit:

```
class WrappedMix {
    private List<Object> oddsAndEnds = ...

    public void add( Integer el ){ oddsAndEnds.add( el ); }
    public void add( Boolean el ){ oddsAndEnds.add( el ); }
    public void add( String el ){ oddsAndEnds.add( el ); }
}
```

Or extend ArrayList with suitable overriding (and overloading),

Although I'm curious why you'd want such a List - it's processing isn't convenient.

Comment: Almost perfect, thx! That's not a `List`, though. But the idea is applicable: Implement a `List<Object>` and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the given object is not `instanceOf` `Integer`, `Boolean` or `String` inside of the `add()` method.

Comment: Make a custom class that extends `List` if you want, then you can have a `CustomList<Object>` and handle the `instanceOf` more easily.